# How to generate nodes from existing network? R

Tags: r, r-sf

I have a road segment called my_line with start point and end point

```
df <- data.frame(id = "a", lon1 = 1, lat1 = 5, lon2 = 7, lat2 = 9)  
dt <- as.data.table(df)

sf <- dt[
  , {
    geometry <- sf::st_linestring(x = matrix(c(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2), ncol = 2))
    geometry <- sf::st_sfc(geometry)
    geometry <- sf::st_sf(geometry = geometry)
  }
  , by = id
]

my_line <- sf::st_as_sf(sf)
```

```
pt <- st_cast(my_line, "POINT")
start <- pt[1,] # create start point
end <- pt[nrow(pt),] # create end point
```

I want to split this road every 2 metres (2-meter interval), and the new points are called new.pt

```
sdist = 2 # split distance

numOfPoints  <-  as.numeric(st_length(my_line) / sdist)
new.pt <- st_line_sample(sf.sf,  numOfPoints, type = "regular") # new points
```

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = sf.sf) +
  geom_sf(data = start, color = 'green') +
  geom_sf(data = end, color = 'red')  + geom_sf(data = new.pt, color = 'black')
```

Now I want to use `new.pt` as to create a new road segment according to this format

(start --> new.pt[1], new.pt[1]--> new.pt[2], new.pt[2] --> end)

i.e. 3 lines; 2 new nodes generated from the existing line

How to do that in R?

Comment: Do you just want to split the lines or do you want to create a directed graph? You can split the lines with points by using `lwgeom::st_split(my_line, new.pt)`.

Comment: See also https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/379107/how-to-split-network-in-equal-piece-line-segments-in-r/